# JSF dynamic creation of a page

Tags: jsf-2

as part of a project I have many users and one of them is the Adminstrator. For the needs of it the Adminstrator is able to see all users registered at a dataTable. There for each entry(a.k.a user) I want to create a link to a profil page named "user_profile" which will be created dynamically for the user clicked. I am new to JSF and I don't know how to do it.

Any help or guidance is appreciated!
Thx in advance!

Thought I don't think it makes a difference here is the datatable:

```
<h:dataTable id="datatable" value="#{adminstratorBean.userArray}" var="u" styleClass="user-table"
                    headerClass="user-table-header" rowClasses="user-table-odd-row,user-table-even-row">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Όνομα</f:facet>
                    #{u.name}
                </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Επώνυμο</f:facet>
                    #{u.surname}
                </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Τηλέφωνο</f:facet>
                    #{u.phone}
                </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Email</f:facet>
                    #{u.email}
                </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Όνομα Χρήστη</f:facet>
                    #{u.username}
                </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Εκρεμμεί έγκριση</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{u.registered ? 'ΟΧΙ' : 'ΝΑΙ' }"></h:outputText>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<h:link>` with `<f:param>` to generate a link to user profile page:

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Profile</f:facet>
    <h:link outcome="user_profile" value="View profile" />
        <f:param name="id" value="#{u.id}" />
    </h:link>
</h:column>
```

Then use `<f:metadata>` tag in user_profile view to handle 'id' parameter.

Read more in [this detailed article](http://balusc.blogspot.ru/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters).